# Natural action on Hilbert Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm reading chapter 4 of Nakajima's Lectures on Hilbert Schemes of Points on Surfaces and I'm a little confused. He says the natural action of $\Gamma$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ gives a natural action on the Hilbert Scheme $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{[N]}$ where  $\Gamma$ is a finite subgroup of $SU(2)$ of order $N$. I am not sure what this action is. I see that there is a natural action on $S^N (\mathbb{C}^2)$, the Nth symmetric product, since that comprises sets of $N$ points. But I can't see the natural action on $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{[N]}$. Am I supposed to have in mind that $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{[N]}$ is a resolution of $S^N (\mathbb{C}^2)$? I imagine this is a really simple statement but I can't think of the answer so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The action on $\mathbf C^2$ corresponds to a dual action on the polynomial ring $\mathbf C[x_1,x_2]$. That sends ideals to ideals, and you can check that if $I$ is an ideal such that $\mathbf C[x_1,x_2]/I$ has length $n$, then the same will be true of the image of $I$. So we get an action on the Hilbert scheme.